# How do I add a surface fill to this on both sides?

Tags: modeling, faces

I have explored all the fill options I could find and I've not been successful yet. I just want this to be a solid 3D shape
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If you feel your previous question was incorrectly [marked as duplicate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates), or the linked posts don't adequately address your issue, go back to your previous question and edit by pressing the *Edit* button below, including information of what you have tried, why it failed and how the duplicates don't address your issue. Once edited the question is automatically queued up for review so it can be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

In *Edit Mode* go to the *Edge Select Mode* or *Vertex Select Mode*, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd> one of the edges, then hit  <kbd>F</kbd>.

Rotate the view to go to the unfilled side of the mesh and do the same.